# Redeem into...?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I just saw a Bank of America commercial that had this use of **redeem**:

[image]

Is the use of **redeem** with the preposition *into* standard...or possible?  To me, it doesn't make sense.  I looked on Google and found other prepositions that can be used with **redeem** such as "at" or "for."  It also seems that **redeem** is usually followed by an object such as "coupon," "tickets" or "points."  There seems to be an exchange process at work with **redeem**, not a one way arrow *into* something.

Comment: Could it be possible that customers get bonus if they redeem points and (somehow) put it back to their BoA account and thus the phrase **redeeming into?** I am certainly not an expert in point redemption policies of major North American banks and this would be my best guess. If not, I think BoA marketers should create an account in ELU :P

Comment: That sure does sound odd. The OED says that *redeem into* is obsolete; their last citation for that is: **1688** Norris *Theory Love* 203 ― As to the redeeming us into the ability of closing with what is discern’d best.

Comment: @tchrist: That's not what I see in OED. There's nothing about sense 6a being obsolete, and they have 6 more citations after 1688 - the last two being 1949 and 1991. I don't see anything remotely unusual about OP's cited usage, where redeeming "reward points" gets you a better "exchange rate" if you redeem into a bank account run by the same outfit that provided you with the credit card.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the usage meant in the ad:

> - to convert (bonds, shares, etc) into cash.

Collins Dictionary

You redeem (sell/convert) a bond into a cash account.

Comment: Get a 10% customer bonus every time you redeem ***your cash back*** into a [Bank of America® checking or savings account](https://www.nerdwallet.com/card-details/card-name/Bank-of-America-BankAmericard-Cash-Rewards-Visa-Signature). It is just what it means in the dictionary.

Comment: Could be what they mean.  I've never seen the word redeem followed by into, so I just thought I would check with some other sharp people and see what their thoughts were on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it sounds funny because we expect redeem to be a transitive verb, but here it's used as an intransitive verb. Thus, I don't think it's solely the presence of *into* immediately after the word, but the absence of an object to receive the result of the action. The object appears to be an ellipsis of a phrase such as "your points" or "your cash rewards." Perhaps they omitted that as being understood, in order to save space and make it faster to read.